# Получение некоторой информации из ViewController во framework'е

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Пишу некий framework и хочу реализовать qrScanner во framework'е следующим образом:

```
class A {
   func a(view: UIViewController) throws -> String {
      let qrScanner = QRScannerViewController()
      view.present(qrScanner, animated: true)
      //здесь получить результат сканирования qr кода в виде строки
      //сделать какие-то действия с qr кодом и отправить результат 
      return result
   }
}
```

Как я могу получить результат ViewController в этой же функции? или как можно реализовать данных функционал, чтобы 'пользователь' вызвал лишь одну функцию

```
let classA = A()
var result = classA.a(view)
```

и получил результат?

Попробовал множество вариантов, не нашел решения. Может кто сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что Вы описали является асинхронным и нельзя просто взять и вернуть готовый результат из метода в качестве возвращаемого значения.

Для подобных сценариев подходит паттерн "Delegate", который широко применяется в iOS разработке.

Но если хотите функцию - используйте [closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html). Пример:

```
func runScanner(from viewController: UIViewController, after completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
     // Ваши создание и вызов сканера, можно "пробросить" completion
     // либо так же получаем данные от сканера и возвращаем результат
     completion(scannedString) 
}
// Используете
yourClassA.runScanner(from: yourController, after: { scannedString in
    print(scannedString)
})
```